# When to use "nul/nulle", and when to use "aucun/aucune"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

> **Aucun doute** que tu trouveras cet engin très utile.
>
> **Nul doute** que tu trouveras cet engin très utile.

---

> Donc, **aucune chance** qu'on puisse en construire une autre...

But you cannot say:

> Donc, **nulle chance** qu'on puisse en construire une autre...

---

In the case of the noun "doute", it seems that you can use both "nul" and "aucun". When it comes to the noun "chance", however, only "aucune" seems to work.

When are "nul/nulle" and "aucun/aucune" interchangeable, and when not?

Comment: What makes you say we cannot say "nulle chance"? A simple google search in [google books](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=nulle+chance&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#q=%22nulle+chance%22&tbm=bks) will tell you you are mistaken.

Comment: It seems that "aucune chance" is used about 150 times more often than "nulle chance". It might not be incorrect, but is "nulle chance" somehow an unpopular option, by any chance?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the word *chance*.  You don't find *nul doute* and  *nulle chance* as often as  *aucun doute* and *aucune chance*  because using *nul* is more formal than using *aucun*. And I would not say it's unpopular, which sounds derogatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les exemples pour l'emploi de *nul* équivalent de *aucun* :

Cela vient du fait que *aucun*, (sens littéraire), avec une valeur positive, a le sens de "quelque, quelque ... que ce soit, qu'il soit"  ; dans les phrases comparatives, dubitatives ou hypothétique il est synonyme de *quelque*.

> Comme si la raison pouvait mépriser aucun fait d'expérience (Barrès)

(Sens courant) avec une valeur négative (accompagné de la particule *ne* ou précédé de *sans*):

> *Cela **ne** fait/Il **n**'y a/**Sans*** aucun doute, tu  trouveras cet engin très utile.

est synonyme de *nul*

> *Nul* doute  que tu trouveras cet engin très utile.

Dans votre premier exemple, *aucun* n'est pas précédé de *de* ou de *sans* de plus il est suivi de *que*, ce qui rend la phrase inélégante.

En revanche, *[Nulle chance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas%20de%20chance%2C%20nulle%20chance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20de%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnulle%20chance%3B%2Cc0)* n'est pas incorrect du tout.

---

*<sup>Ces références sont extraites du petit Robert.</sup>*